# Jquery nestable (angular)

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone let me know how to pass in the maxDepth option to this jquery nestable but in angularjs version? The documentation says it exposes $nestableProvider but I am not sure how to use that.

https://github.com/kamilkp/ng-nestable

```
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div ng-nestable ng-model="nodes">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select ng-model="dDescription" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">- Select -</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        {{$item.text}}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

---

Controller

```
$scope.nodes = [
    {
        item: { text: 'Item 13' },
        children: []
    },
    {
        item: { text: 'Item 14' },
        children: []
    },
    {
        item: { text: 'Item 15' },
        children: [
            {
                item: { text: 'Item 16' },
                children: []
            },
            {
                item: { text: 'Item 17' },
                children: []
            },
            {
                item: { text: 'Item 18' },
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Found out the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$nestable.defaultOptions = { maxDepth: 999 };

Comment: where did u put this? in the controller? it doesn't have any effect to the defaultOptions whatsoever...